# Can' t close OSK.exe under Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, win32gui

I use below code to open osk.exe

```
HINSTANCE Dlg::ExecuteOSK()
{
    typedef BOOL (WINAPI * LPFN_IsWow64Process)(HANDLE, PBOOL);
    typedef BOOL (WINAPI * LPFN_Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection)(PVOID *);
    typedef BOOL (WINAPI * LPFN_Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection)(PVOID);
    LPFN_IsWow64Process fnIsWow64Process = NULL;
    LPFN_Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection fnWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection = NULL;
    LPFN_Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection fnWow64RevertWow64FsRedirection = NULL;
    fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_IsWow64Process) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "IsWow64Process");
    fnWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection = (LPFN_Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");
    fnWow64RevertWow64FsRedirection = (LPFN_Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection");
    BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;
    PVOID OldValue = NULL;
    HINSTANCE handle;
    if (NULL == fnIsWow64Process || NULL == fnWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection || NULL == fnWow64RevertWow64FsRedirection)
    {
        handle = ::ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "OSK", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    }
    else
    {
        fnIsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64);

        if (TRUE == bIsWow64)
        {
            fnWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue);
            handle = ::ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "OSK", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
            fnWow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldValue);
        }
        else
        {
            handle = ::ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "OSK", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
        }
    }
    return handle;
}
```

And then, I want to close the osk.exe when user press enter.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(
  _In_ HWND   hwnd,
   _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    char name[256];
    GetClassName( hwnd, name, sizeof(name) );
    if(strcmp(name,"OSKMainClass") == 0)
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE  , NULL, NULL); //I have tried WM_DESTROY
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL Dlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {       
        int nKey = (int)pMsg->wParam;       

        switch(nKey)            
        {
        case VK_RETURN:     
            EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);

        }
    }

    return CBitmapDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

However, this part of code cannot be used to close osk.exe successful.

I have tried to catch another window, it can be closed successfully.

Does it is an issue on Windows 10?

Comment: this is not a c syntax, please remove the c tag

Comment: Don't use `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()` to run OSK on Wow64. The preferred way to bypass `system32` redirection is to [use the `sysnative` alias instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx): "*32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting `%windir%\Sysnative` for `%windir%\System32`. WOW64 recognizes `Sysnative` as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection.*"

Comment: If you use `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute()`, you can then use `TerminateProcess()` on the returned process handle, instead of using window messages (which won't work anyway due to UIPI).

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you looking to manifest of `osk.exe` you can view here next - `uiAccess="true"` this is [User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx) , also read about similar problem [UIAccess in Manifest Files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4d2e1358-af95-4f4f-b239-68ec7e2525a9/uiaccess-in-manifest-files?forum=windowssecurity)

because `osk.exe` have `uiAccess="true"` in manifest it have `Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level` in token. but your app, if running under UAC not elevated, usual have `Medium Mandatory Level`. as result:

> A lower-privilege process cannot:
>
> - Use SendMessage or PostMessage to application windows running with    higher rights. These APIs return success but silently drop the window 
>     message.

but if your application get `High Mandatory Level` in token - you can close `osk.exe` by next code:

```
if (HWND hwnd = FindWindow(L"OSKMainClass", 0))
{
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
}
```

so you need have `<requestedExecutionLevel level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'/>` in manifest or somehow run your application as elevated